# Android - Open AdView with GooglePlay

Tags: android, admob, double-click

I have an app that shows an ad with Google DoubleClick, this ad will always open a google play app, but when I click the ad, always ask me if I want to open it with google play or web browser. I would like to force the ad to open google play, without allowing the user to choose. Is there a way to do it?

This is the code with I call the ad:

```
    adView = new AdView(this, new AdSize(320,175), MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
    ly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ly.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the URL for the ad to use the old Android market syntax. Ie market:// etc.